# How to log messages in to a file when deployed on remote server

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

In my spring boot project , I used logback.xml when I run my project locally it is logging messages in to specified file but when I deployed on remote server it is still writing in to catalina.out file in tomcat. 
Here is my code.
logback.xml

```
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- Log message format -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- Setting the root level of logging to INFO -->
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I specified these dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In application.properties file I specified logging file property.

```
logging.file=var/log/sampleproject_logging.log
```

In application-dev.properties file I specified log file for remote server.

```
spring.profiles.active = dev

#logging info
#logging.file=var/log/sampleproject/sampleproject_logging.log
```

when I run locally , it created folder under project structure and logged messages.when deployed on remote server it is still logging into catalina.out file. How to write in to the specified log file on remote server? I tried logback-spring.xml and logging.config property nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing "FILE" Appender definition in your logback.xml

Add something like this

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>yourlogName.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: I tried this one also. I created logback-local.xml and logback-dev.xml and added this <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">     
    <file>var/log/sampleproject_logging.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

Comment: I created application-dev.proper file and specified  logging.config=classpath:logback-dev.xml.when I run locally it is displaying on console and and in file as well .

Comment: but on remote it is not writing in to the specified file.